# How to encode a pre-existing text file to utf-8 in separate file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, encode

I'm attempting to encode a pre-existing text file and write it in utf-8. I've made a menu in which the user is asked for which text file they would like to encode, but after that I am absolutely lost. I was looking at a previous post and I incorporated that code into my code, however I am unsure of how it works or what I'm doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import codecs

def getMenuSelection():
    print "\n"
    print "\t\tWhich of the following files would you like to encode?"
    print "\n"
    print "\t\t================================================"
    print "\t\t1. hamletQuote.txt"
    print "\t\t2. RandomQuote.txt"
    print "\t\t3. WeWillRockYou.txt"    
    print "\t\t================================================"
    print "\t\tq or Q to quit"
    print "\t\t================================================"

    print ""

    selection = raw_input("\t\t")
    return selection

again = True

while (again == True):

    choice = getMenuSelection()

    if choice.lower() == 1 :

        with codecs.open(hamletQuote.txt,'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
            text = f.read()

        with codecs.open(hamletQuote.txt,'w',encoding='utf8') as f:
            f.write(text)

    if choice.lower() == 2 :

        with codecs.open(RandomQuote.txt,'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
            text = f.read()

        with codecs.open(RandomQuote.txt,'w',encoding='utf8') as f:
            f.write(text)

    if choice.lower() == 3 :

        with codecs.open(WeWillRockYou.txt,'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
            text = f.read()

        with codecs.open(WeWillRockYou.txt,'w',encoding='utf8') as f:
            f.write(text)

    elif choice.lower() == "q":
        again = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work correctly, though you need to make the filenames strings. Your input filename is also the same as the output filename, so the input file will be overwritten. You can fix this by naming the output file something different:

```
with codecs.open("hamletQuote.txt",'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()

with codecs.open("hamletQuote2.txt",'w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

If your curious how it works, `codecs.open` opens an encoded file in the given mode; in this case `r` which means read mode. `w` refers to write mode. `f` refers to the file object which has several methods including `read()` and `write()` (which you used).

When you use the `with` statement it simplifies opening the file. It ensures clean-up is always used. Without the `with` block, you would have to specify `f.close()` after you have finished working with the file.

Comment: Thank you! However I was wondering where I could find the new encoded file? This is most likely a stupid question, but I'm so lost.

Comment: The new file will be put in same directory where the script was run from. I only just realized your input and output filenames are the same. So when you run the script hamletQuote.txt is being overwritten with the new utf8 encoded file also called hamletQuote.txt. I updated my answer. You need to name the output file something different if you want to keep the input file.

Comment: use `io` instead of `codecs`. It's Python 3 compatible and the Universal line support works

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the regular `open` statement and open the file as binary and write the encoded text to `utf-8`, you will need to open the file as regular read mode since it's not encoded:

```
with open("hamletQuote.txt", 'r') as read_file:
    text = read_file.read()

with open("hamletQuote.txt", 'wb') as write_file:
    write_file.write(text.encode("utf-8"))
```

But if you insist on using `codecs`, you can do this:

```
with codecs.open("hamletQuote.txt", 'r') as read_file:
    text = read_file.read()

with codecs.open("hamletQuote.txt", 'wb', encoding="utf-8") as write_file:
    write_file.write(text.encode("utf-8"))
```